# How can I insert a list into a paragraph?

Tags: html, html-lists

I have a list that I want to insert into a paragraph. Yet, this is not valid HTML. How can I at least imitate having a list inside a paragraph?

Comment: What would be wrong with closing the paragraph tag, opening a list, writing the list, closing the list, then opening a new paragraph tag (which your original closing paragraph would match)?

Comment: Because <p> tag appears automatically when user selects new paragraph and if I would close it then there would not be possibility to edit information in the list. I let edit only content in the paragraphs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can display text as a list without using list markup. At the simplest,

```
<p>Paragraph text goes here. And then the list:<br>
• list item<br>
• another list item<br>
• yet another<br>
Paragraph text continues here.</p>
```

Of course you can use any item markers here instead of bullets.

If you need to style the items, wrap them inside inline markup:

```
<span class=li>• list item</span><br>
```

To indent the items, for example, you would then set e.g. `.li { padding-left: em; }`.

Comment: If it is a list, mark it up as such. While this may work, it is still poor markup.

Comment: @Zak Henry, a word is a list (an ordered sequence) of characters. Yet we don’t mark each word as a list. We use `ul` or `ol` to get certain types of set-off lists (bulleted or numbered in certain ways). If they cannot be used in a particular syntactic context (like inside a `p` element), it’s just common sense to consider other ways of getting the desired result.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela it looks so evil I can hardly believe it's valid... but it is :)

Answer (score 0):

You could combine nl2br() with \n

```
<?php

echo nl2br("First paragraph \n\n Your Second paragraph \n\n Your third paragraph.\n\n");

echo "First paragraph <br/><br/> Your Second paragraph <br/><br/> Your third paragraph.";

echo "<p>First paragraph</p> <p>Your Second paragraph</p><p>Your third paragraph</p>";
```